# Authorize adb in recovery mode

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb

I need to authorize `adb` in recovery mode on my Galaxy S3 I9300 (international edition) in order to make a backup of my files.

The problem is that I cannot boot the cyanogenmod which is install on the phone and I don't know why.

Currently I have ClockworkMod Recovery 6.0.4.3 and when I try `adb pull /sdcard/DCIM` I get the following message:

`error: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.`

Please help me, I have a lot of valuable information on my phone which I need to recover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pull the files with ADB from my phone I flashed the latest [TWRP](https://twrp.me/) recovery with [ODIN](http://odindownload.com/) (3.0.7, not the latest), then by default you have an authorized ADB devise in recovery, so I just entered

`adb pull /sdcard/*`

and waited for the files to transfer.